# templated conversion constructor fails to access protected data members

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a templated class Rect with conversion constructor which allows conversion between Rect to Rect and vice a versa. But when compiling the code, the compiler gives an error stating the constructor can't access the protected members of the class.
Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template< typename T >
class Rect{
protected:
  T width, height;
public:
  Rect(T a, T b){
    width = a;
    height = b;
  }
  template< typename U >
  Rect(Rect<U> const &r){
    width = r.width;
    height = r.height;
  }
  int area(){
    return width*height;
  }
};

int main(){
  Rect<int> a(3,4);
  Rect<float> b(a);
  cout<<b.area()<<endl;
}
```

And here is the compilation error:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Rect<T>::Rect(const Rect<U>&) [with U = int, T = float]’:
test.cpp:28:18:   instantiated from here
test.cpp:10:7: error: ‘int Rect<int>::width’ is protected
test.cpp:18:5: error: within this context
test.cpp:10:14: error: ‘int Rect<int>::height’ is protected
test.cpp:19:5: error: within this context
```

I want to solve this problem without using template specialization and making friend classes. As far as I know you can't declare constructors as friends. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I have made corrections to semantics. So the constructor I am trying to build is really a conversion constructor.

**Edit2:** Corrected the program.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599171/c-class-member-access-problem-with-templates/

Comment: Why are `width` and `height` declared to be of type `int` instead of type `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As K-ballo mentioned, `Rect<int>` and `Rect<float>` are different types, and do not have access to each others' private and protected members.  You can explicitly allow this by adding the following template friend declaration to your class ([like so](http://ideone.com/DGajI)):

```
template <typename U> friend class Rect;
```

Semantically, this means "for any type `U`, give the class `Rect<U>` access to my private and protected members" -- it is an outgoing permission grant from every `Rect` instantiation to every other `Rect` instantiation.

Note that this won't be necessary if you add accessors for `width` and `height` (as K-ballo suggests) -- then you can just use those accessors in the conversion constructor and forgo the friend definition entirely.  I would prefer his solution over mine; I give mine merely as another possible option and to introduce to you a concept (friends, and specifically template friends) that you might not be familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

First thing you should know is that a *template constructor* is never a *copy constructor*. Second thing is that `Rect<T>` and `Rect<U>` where `T != U` are different unrelated classes, as unrelated as a `std::string` and an `std::vector`.

You should offer some way to access `width` and `height`, and your *conversion constructors* should use such access methods to create the new `Rect`.

Comment: @cdhowie This results in partial specialization error during compilation. Maybe if you could provide us with a working code that would be better. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @gibraltar: _friend templates_ are a complicated beast, wont your `Rect`s need to offer a way to know their _width_ and _height_ anyway?