# Friendship Throughout Same Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider the following:

```
template<int N>
class A
{
public:
    A() : i(N) {}

    template<int K>
    void foo(A<K> other)
    {
        i = other.i; // <-- other.i is private
    }

private:
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    A<1> a1;
    A<2> a2;
    a1.foo(a2);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make 'other.i' visible *without* moving member *i* and *foo* to a common base class or doing something mad as adding *friend class A<1>*?

That is, is there a way to make templates of the same template class friends?

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem with this code.

Comment: Except that it won't work because i is private...

Comment: Curious, GCC agrees, but I could have sworn that this was perfectly legal. Oh well.

Comment: I usually try my code before posting ;)

Comment: *"Friendship Throughout Same Template Class"*... let's have friendship all around!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++03 did not provide a mechanism for this, but C++11 does.

```
template<int N2> friend class A;
```

should friend *all* instantiations of A.

Comment: Well I'd be damned, c++11 to the resque.

Comment: @JensÅkerblom _resqueue_ FTFY?

Comment: Are you sure this feature is from c++11? (old [gcc 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/rOJ3hB) seems to accept it).

Comment: @JesseGood: It was a common extension. Also, gcc 4.3.4 supported some C++11 features apart from this- rvalue refs (an early version) if I recall.

Comment: I did some digging, and found the unaccepted answer [to this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599171/c-class-member-access-problem-with-templates) explains it well. So, it was part of C++03, but there was a defect report [about it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#602). (+1 anyways for something I didn't know).