# Defining operation between different types with templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I created a class template (called `ThreeVector`) and added functionality to allow the addition operation between different types. Here's the relevant portion of my header file:

```
template <class T>
class ThreeVector {
    private:
        T mx;
        T my;
        T mz;
        public:
        ThreeVector<T>(T, T, T);
            template <class X> 
        ThreeVector<T> operator+(const ThreeVector<X>&);
}

template <class T> 
ThreeVector<T>::ThreeVector(T x, T y, T z) { //initialize vector
    mx = x;
    my = y;
    mz = z;
}

template<class T> template<class X>
ThreeVector<T> ThreeVector<T>::operator+(const ThreeVector<X>& a) {
    ThreeVector<T> v(mx+a.mx, my+a.my, mz+a.mz);
    return v;
}
```

And then I call it like this:

```
ThreeVector<double> a(1,2,3);
ThreeVector<float> b(4,5,6);
ThreeVector<double> c=a+b;
```

This gives me the error:

```
ThreeVector.h: In member function 'ThreeVector<T> ThreeVector<T>::operator+(const ThreeVector<X>&) [with X = float, T = double]':
ThreeVectorTest.cxx:33:   instantiated from here
ThreeVector.h:8: error: 'float ThreeVector<float>::mx' is private
ThreeVector.h:122: error: within this context
ThreeVector.h:9: error: 'float ThreeVector<float>::my' is private
ThreeVector.h:123: error: within this context
ThreeVector.h:10: error: 'float ThreeVector<float>::mz' is private
ThreeVector.h:124: error: within this context
make: *** [ThreeVectorTest] Error 1
```

It works fine if both a and b are `<double>`. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Class member access problem with templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599171/c-class-member-access-problem-with-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access privileges of class templates can be a little confusing.

Say you have a simple class template.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
   public:
      A() {}

   private:
      T data;
};
```

When you create instances of `A` using,

```
A<int> a1;
A<float> a2;
```

You are defining two classes using the template. It's as if you had two classes:

```
class AInt
{
   public:
     AInt() {}
   private:
     int data;
};
```

and

```
class AFloat
{
   public:
     AFloat() {}
   private:
     float data;
};
```

It's easy to see that `AInt` doesn't have access to the private section of `AFloat` and vice versa.

That is also true with `A<int>` and `A<float>`.

In order for you make your `operator+` function work, you have two choices:

1. Make the members of the class template public.
2. Have a friend declaration like:

   ```
   template <class T>
   class ThreeVector {
      private:
         T mx;
         T my;
         T mz;
      public:
         ThreeVector<T>(T, T, T);

         template <class X> 
            ThreeVector<T> operator+(const ThreeVector<X>&);

         template <class X> friend class ThreeVector;
   };
   ```